# Animating certain elements after others have finished their animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I'm trying to build a landing page with some neat animations.

I want my `span` elements to show only after my `content` div finishes its animation.

Any idea how I can tackle this?

Here is my code and a [link](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/mQGpVY) to CodePen:

PUG:

```
div.landing-page
  div.content
    span J
    span H
  input(type='button' id='button' value='click')
```

SASS:

```
html
  background: gray
  .landing-page
    .content
      width: 200px
      height: 2px
      background: black
      position: absolute
      left: 50%
      top: 50%
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
      animation: fade 2s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards
      span
        color: white
    .animated
      animation: grow 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards
    input#button
      position: absolute
      left: 50%
      top: 48%
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%)

@keyframes fade
  0%
    opacity: 0
  100%
    opacity: 1
@keyframes grow
  0%
    width: 0%
  70%
    width: 100%
    height: 2px
  100%
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.content').addClass('animated');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add

```
overflow: hidden
```

to .content in css. This would hide the span until there is enough space for it, after the animation is finished.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is a very elegant solution. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to uset settimeout. This function triggers any js function or command aftger X miliseconds. So you just need to time it. Again, not the most beautiful way, but would work. for example:

```
setTimeout( FunctioName, 2000);
```

do note that function name without the () => only the name.